# PyQT and SQLite with multiple users

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5, qtsql, qsqldatabase

We are trying to write concurrently to a SQLite database, using WAL mode, to a network location. We don't have the privileges of having a server-based database (Postgres, MySQL, etc) so we have to utilise SQLite only unfortunately. The basic application we're developing needs to make use of the SQLite database and the user has the values calculated on their UI (using PyQT5) which then needs to be written back to the SQLite database.

When one person is using the program, it writes to the database with no issues. However, when multiple users try to write their output to the database via the code, there seems to be an issue which we can't resolve and it's this we would like to get any solutions on if any others have encountered it.

What we're finding is the user who gets their inputs to run last on their UI, has their figures updated to the database (two files, a -wal file and a -shm file are created) but one of the other user's data doesn't get recorded to the database, even though they can see it on their UI.

First, here is the SQL code to create the database and enter data:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
"Name" TEXT,
"Age" INTEGER,
"City" TEXT,
"Bonus" REAL,
"Department" TEXT);

INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age, City, Bonus, Department) VALUES ('Sam', 30, 'DL', NULL, 'Sales');
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age, City, Bonus, Department) VALUES ('James', 40, 'NC', NULL, 'IT');
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age, City, Bonus, Department) VALUES ('Craig', 50, 'LD', NULL, 'Finance');
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age, City, Bonus, Department) VALUES ('John', 60, 'MC', NULL, 'HR');
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age, City, Bonus, Department) VALUES ('Tracy', 48, 'DH', NULL, 'Customer Support');
INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Age, City, Bonus, Department) VALUES ('Sarah', 39, 'LP', NULL, 'Marketing');
```

Below, is the code for the program:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
    
class TableViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #createDB()
        
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName('sample.db')
    
        # try to open the database
        if not self.db.open():
            raise QSqlError("Could not open the database")

        # this will give you the whole table:
        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)   
        self.model.setTable('Employee')
        self.model.select()

        self.tview = QTableView(self)
        self.tview.setModel(self.model)
        h_header = self.tview.horizontalHeader()
        h_header.setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tview)
        
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        widget.setFixedHeight(350)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.copy_btn = QPushButton()
        self.copy_btn.setText("Calculate")
        layout.addWidget(self.copy_btn, alignment=Qt.AlignAbsolute)
        self.copy_btn.clicked.connect(self.Calculate)
        self.show()

    def Calculate(self):
        for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            record = self.model.record(i)
            department = record.value("Department")
            if department == 'Sales':
                record.setValue("Bonus", 1500)
            if department == 'IT':
                record.setValue("Bonus", 3000)
            if department == 'Finance':
                record.setValue("Bonus", 2000)
            
            self.model.setRecord(i, record)
        self.model.submitAll()        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tv = TableViewer()
    tv.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To replicate the issue we're having, the other user would be trying to enter the following in their Calculate function:

```
def Calculate(self):
        for i in range(self.model.rowCount()):
            record = self.model.record(i)
            department = record.value("Department")
            if department == 'HR':
                record.setValue("Bonus", 2500)
            if department == 'Customer Support':
                record.setValue("Bonus", 1000)
            if department == 'Marketing':
                record.setValue("Bonus", 500)
            
            self.model.setRecord(i, record)
        self.model.submitAll()
```

The SQLite database has the following settings:

[image]

Any help to resolve this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having trouble to visualize where your db is located? You say there's no server, so, how all clients access the db? Do they use some kind of P2P connection? Or maybe do you indeed use some kind of server, but it's more like a 3rd party app you don't have access to the source code, just its API (like dropbox, for example)? Can you briefly explain what is it?

Comment: It’s SQLite so a serverless database file  which for us is on a work network drive.

Comment: @R41nMak3R Sorry but that doesn't really answer what asked. Local network file access may have different ways of dealing with multiple user access, and that context is of utmost importance: due to its architecture, SQLite has no way of knowing the source of a modification: most importantly, there is absolutely no way of properly synchronizing multiple user access to the same file/database, and since different network file access may use fail-safe systems to prevent concurrent access to the same file, the result is that the user may just be working on a local "copy".

Comment: @R41nMak3R In reality, what you want to achieve is probably not possible, unless you provide some way of synchronizing access to database. If you can have access to the "server", then a possible solution is to create a server-side app with its own network API to allow database access. If you can't, but the machines can communicate with each other, then maybe you may consider some sort of p2p access that uses each nodes to synchronize the database, which won't be easy to implement, but still feasible. In any case, I sincerely doubt you can achieve all that as simply as you hoped.

Comment: @R41nMak3R Consider the simple case of two people accessing the same "network file" X, which is a basic text file. User A opens file X and starts editing it, and user B does the same. Then user A *saves* their editing, and the result is that the server has the new version of file X. User B will *never* see those changes, even after saving their modifications. I won't go too into SQLite details, but when concurrent access to the same file happens, you need to be aware of the file system capabilities. Even for local access (and WAL), that can be an issue, because the system may not be aware of »

Comment: @R41nMak3R » concurrent changes made by other network access, and may not even notify the local OS about those changes. The result of all the above is that, even if SQLite may *believe* that the change has been applied and even if the change has actually been applied, due to the way it works and its optimizations, it has absolutely **no way** to know about changes to the database made by others. Using a *further* layer such as the QtSql module even complicate things, because it is an abstraction (and multi-system) layer that has no way to know about external changes, especially in this case.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for the explanation. I've used the example in my question here as a basic use case of what we're trying to achieve, but the actual application is a lot more complicated - it's just the write-back part that is essentially what is in my question here. It uses MVC (model-view-controllers) to access the data from the SQLite database and can be updated on the db. Part of the program runs a calculation separately, which then needs to update on the UI table, then this needs to be written back to the db.

Comment: @musicamante Would it be possible to apply a lock to the db or to check if the db is "free" (not busy/locked), then get the other user to wait for it be available again, before trying to write back to the SQLite db? Thank you for your insights - it's very much appreciated!

Comment: @musicamante We thought the solution was to use WAL and then autocheckpoint that so the update gets applied to the db. It's frustrating that it works for one person (the latter to press the 'Calculate' button) but the first person's update doesn't get applied, possibly just sat in the shm or wal file.

Comment: In oder to test wether the db file is shared across all users, you could rewrite all clients to watch that db file periodically, like every 0.5s. Sure, the app may run very slow, but for educational purposes, you'll learn if user A is accessing user B file, or just their own local copies. That said, if you're sharing that db, its entirely possoble to "lock" the db when a user is editing it, but even if it is possible, it might not be fast enough (sounds good on paper, in realiy its not really). I suggest you to keep thinhs simple, specially if you dont want to buy/use a dedicated server.

Comment: @CarlHR Unfortunately, just watching the file is not enough, as it completely depends on how the OS eventually synchronizes the local copy with the remote one. It's been a while since I last used such systems, but I remember issues even for systems known to provide "proper" network synchronization, and the further abstraction layer SQLite adds eventually increases the unreliability. Knowing more about the actual remote file access system would help, but I still believe that, for such scenario, a p2p-like implementation would probably a better choice, since it's server-less by nature.

Comment: @musicamante there're more ways to watch if a file has changed, given that we just want to detect wether the changes are propagated to each client. By watching it I don't mean using a module to take care of that job. The OP could use the [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat) function, though yes, it may be OS dependant, or simply read the file once, store it as an old version, and keep reading its contents again and again, comparing the bytes with the old version to detect if there are any changes. There's no need to rely just on the OS states.